# English language with Norwegian locale+keyboard?

Tags: server, keyboard-layout, locale

Wanted to try out Ubuntu Server, and I've been stopped by a stupid issue.

During the install I choose English language (since that's what I want). Then I choose Norway as my country, since that's where I live. On the next screen however, it asks me for locale and it only gives me en_* options?

Not being able to select anything better I have to go with en_US. I'm also not able to select a Norwegian keyboard layout during the install, which of course is annoying. Working in the terminal with the wrong keyboard layout is basically impossible (Unless you have that other layout in your fingers... which I don't...).

So, what do I do? How can I fix this? I want to try out Ubuntu Server with english language, but with Norwegian locale and keyboard layout. In regular Ubuntu this was not a problem at all.

---

**Update:** Temporary "solution" I found was to reinstall and remember to select both language *and* keyboard layout in the initial menu you get when booting from the installation media. You can select layout by using one of the F keys, and seems like it remembers this choice through the installation. At least the keys seem to do the right thing now :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone else have this problem - try this command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the console keyboard setup by running the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

The above command lets you specify quite a few options in addition to your keyboard layout, but you should be able to follow the instructions fairly easily.

Comment: Tried that one, and most of the stuff it asked me about was pretty greek to me. Nothing about keyboard layout either as far as I can remember.

Comment: You can not change the layout to Norwegian by using console-setup